# Почему char-массив должен заканчиваться '\0', а int-массив - нет?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Почему char-массив должен заканчиваться `'\0'`, а int-массив(или какой-то другой тип) - не заканчивается никаким терминатором?

Comment: Вы путаете `char` массив и строку в Си - а это как говорят в Одессе - две большие разницы :)

Comment: Откуда вообще появилось такое предположение?

Comment: @Barmaley  да да, но только это не совсем правда:)

Comment: ой спасибо всем, теперь придется думать кому галочку ставить :)

Comment: ещё рано думать ..

Comment: а ну подождем еще

Answer (score 4, accepted):

char массив может заканчиваться чем угодно (например, в DOS строки могли заканчиваться [символом $](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7638/why-did-dos-use-dollar-terminated-strings)). А может и ничем. Но так договорились и многие-многие функции закладываются на то, что строки заканчиваются нулем.

Но почему строке нужно заканчиваться чем-то? все потому что си-строки (char-массив) не хранит нигде своего размера. И люди посчитали, что один байт в конце дешевле, чем 2-3-4 байта в начале строки или где то ещё. А в Паскале решили, что один байт в начале будет хорошо, а индексация строки с 1 - это естественно в Паскале. В других случаях длину часто хранят по "отрицательному смещению" - тоже получается интересно.

Но почему все таки ноль, а не 1 или 147? Да просто на уровне команд процессора с нулем сравнивать значительно легче. А значит функции, которые на это закладываются (strlen, к примеру) будут работать чуточку быстрее. А 40 лет назад чуточку быстрее было очень важно.

Почему же int массив не заканчиватся нулем? Потому что символ '\0' - не печатный и это его естественное использование для строк. А вот для массива int - 0 может быть вполне нормальным числом. Хотя иногда используются массивы с нулем в конце.

Comment: Я бы принял этот ответ

Comment: отличный ответ, спасибо!

Comment: Я благодарен Вам, о мудрец непокорного языка C++. Вы дали мне понять этот момент. Низкий поклон таким, как Вы, познавший всю истинну этого языка !

Comment: Вот только пасклевская строка по дефолту ограничена длиной 80 символов, а не 255 символов. А это уже не только формат.

Comment: Массив флоатов тоже nan не заканчивается.

Comment: ні. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/String_Types_(Delphi) & https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/length.html.

Answer (score 2):

Массив **не** должен так заканчиваться.

```
char carr [ ] = { '1' , '2' } ;
int  iarr [ ] = { 1 , 2 } ;
```

А строки в исходном коде добавляют нуль для удобства программисту. Так как в старой Си библиотеке передавались только указатели на начало строк, а аргумент длины - нет. По-этому букву с кодом ноль `\00` сделали знаком конца строки.

Comment: И только сейчас, грешная душа моя поняла, что программирование - это целое искусство жизни ! Спасибо!

Comment: Какой такой мифический аргумент длины? И причём здесь удобство?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему char-массив должен заканчиваться '\0'

Он не должен, не такого правила. Просто многие функции работы со строками из стандартной библиотеки рассчитывают на это, и таким способом определяют длину массива.

Я видел в кое-каких библиотеках функции, которые требуют этого для массивов интов.

Еще, например, `argv` - заканчивается нулем, а это вообще массив указателей.

Answer (score -1):

Ни тот, ни другой массив ничем заканчиваться не должен. Но для чего Вы используете каждый из них? Обычно массив чаров интерпретируется не как массив, а как строка, каждый элемент массива представляет символ этой строки. А какова длина этой строки? Функции, работающие со строками, не имеют доступа к своему фактическому параметру и не могут измерить длину строки как size_t L=sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]). Поэтому есть две возможности и их комбинация: или завершать строку специальным терминальным символом, или хранить длину отдельно, или дублировать терминальный символ отдельным числом. Стандартные функции написаны в предположении, что строка нуль-терминальная, то есть тот самый специальный символ – ноль. Терминальный символ – это не символ самой строки, а признак того, что предыдущий символ последний. А массив интов – это обычно именно массив интов и интерпретируете его Вы. И именно Вы должны или зашить размер массива в текст функций, или решить, как этот размер передавать. Но если, например,

```
static const char digitals[16]={'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
```

, то завершать его нолём как раз **не** принято. Но обратите внимание: в этом случае массив чаров – это **именно массив** чаров, а не строка.